# Magento 2 : Allow special character at the end in password

Tags: magento2, password, regex

I want to allow special character at the end of string, something like Test123@. I have used the following regex. Can anyone help me how can i acheive it

[^a-zA-Z0-9]

Thanks

Comment: You want to allow a special character at any place (like start, middle, or at the end )  or you want a special character only at the end?

Comment: I want to allow it at any place

Comment: I added an answer please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can special character which you want to add.

> ^[ A-Za-z0-9_@.#&+-]*$